# Is there a way to set Allure attributes dynamically?

Tags: c#, unit-testing

In my testing scenario, I've set up a few parameterized tests in order to test various data inputs to a function. I'm also using Allure to generate my test report. My issue is that if I set Allure attributes for things like suite and sub suite for instance in the test class itself, it shows the same static data for every test entry in the report. What I'd like to do is to have the sub suite attribute read something like "Test data for input " and then either input 1, 2, 3, etc., depending on which input is being ran through at the time. The input object does contain an index number property, so getting the specific input number isn't an issue, I just need a way to write that to the Allure attribute.

The C# based allure implementation I'm using does have an AllureLifecycle class, which has in instance property (Which from what I understand should give access to the currently running test instance), and then a UpdateTestCase method. What I'm not sure of though is whether the suite and attributes like it can even be updated using this method, or if they are required to be set via data annotations.

What I guess I'm trying to figure out is if what I want to do is even possible? Am I on the right track here?

Comment: I'm not familiar with Allure, BUT in uint testing you don't provide deferent parameters to the same method, 
every input represent a  test case so every test case should be in a deferent unit test FACT . 
hope this some how helps you

Comment: Hi @IbraHim, Sorry I wasn't particularly clear in my original post. The inputs aren't different types, just different values. It's like if I was testing a method to compute the sum of 2 integers, I can run that multiple times by passing in a list of operands and verifying the result matches what is expected. It's a similar concept here

Comment: every input should result a different result, 
so each one should be in a test [FACT]